# stuck with basics of ADF pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have just started with ADF development, and I am stuck with the following requirement.

- source - cosmos db collection
- target - azure data lake gen2 storage
- requirement -
  1. read a cosmos collection
  2. FOR EACH RECORD in the query output, create separate output files in
  data lake gen 2 storage
  3. from same query output, create ANOTHER SINGLE FILE with fields separated
  by pipe character(here I need to transform the JSON query output to a
  tabular pipe delimited data structure)
- the place where I am stuck -
  to read from cosmos collection, I have used a copy data activity, however
  I do not understand what to put in the sink of this activity in order to
  pass the query output to the next activity(for-each or another copy
  activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of `Lookup activity` to get the collection, `CopyActivity` to write files to ADLS.

In the below example, I have used a field in the record a parameter to iterate over each record i.e `@string(item().CustomerID)`, but you can use as per your collection.
And modify the query as per your need.

(requirement no. **1**)

**CosmosDB source query:**

```
@concat('select * from c where c.CustomerID = ',variables('ids'))
```

Then make sure you have the right files extension mentioned in the sink properties and corresponding dataset properties as well. I have used .tsv with pipe(|) delimited and another is a .csv file. (as per your requirement no. **2** & **3**)

[image]

Comment: It's important for the OP to provide specific details for what they've done and where they are stuck, vs a high level requirement, to avoid having to create a custom tutorial (such as what you just did). Please request clarification from the OP before doing something like this, in the future.

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT: to be honest, I do not have to use the @item().customer_id field to re-query the cosmos table again. I would use @item().customer_id from each record to write into separate files(**the @item() would have all the details needed to be written into the respective output files**).  is there a way to use the @item() only as input to copy data activity inside the foreach acitivity? thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @SubhashGhai, the fact that the CopyActivity will consider as input only the source dataset provided, unlike using streams or partitioning in DataFlow, in your scenario we need to have a single file for each record i.e. CopyActivity source should have one record only at a time to be able to write to a single file at sink. So I employed, `ForEach` to iterate through all the records, set source query to fetch one record at a time and write as a single file to sink. I think there is no other way than to use `query` or `table` to fetch from source.